# Tableau - SQL Server Connection

Tags: tableau-api

I have installed Tableau Desktop 9.3 on my Machine. When I try connecting to Microsoft SQL Server as per [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialgateway.org/connecting-tableau-to-sql-server/), I don't see any to a server or to a file option.

It just shows as below

[image]

How can I connect to server or file using tableau?

Answer (score 0):

You will see a option called To a Server option below where you will find sql server connection.